# div expands off screen instead of scrolling

Tags: html, css

I inherited some code and I'm having trouble figuring out how to prevent a container with a large number of items is overflowing off the visible screen instead of a scroll bar appearing. I have made a jsfiddle to demonstrate the issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/yellavon/vo437qaL/

```
<div style="padding:20px;width:100%;">
  <div style="border-width:1px;border-style:solid;width:100%;height:100%" class="k-widget">
    <panel style="display: flex; position: relative; flex-direction: column; height: 100%; width: 100%;">
      <panelrow style="position: relative; display: flex; flex-shrink: 0; padding: 5px; font-size: 1.3em;" class="bg-gray k-widget">Title </panelrow>
```

Comment: `body{ overflow: hidden; }` is the culprit

Comment: Thanks! That makes the entire body scrollable, which on the actual page will scroll the menu bar elements that need to  be static. Is it possible to keep the body overflow:hidden and have the child element with all the divs not expand past the visible area?

Answer (score 1):

Notice you have `overflow: hidden;` property set on the body. Removing it will resolve your problem. Read up on overflow [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) for more information.